# ECharts / JS - Format Time Int to H:M:S within Tooltip

Tags: javascript, formatting, echarts

I am trying to change a time int, such as 010511 into a human readable format of 01:05:11 for both the tooltip, and YAxis of Echarts.

Note that this isn't a timestamp, and is a stopwatch-type piece of data, always starting from 00:00:00 and going up.

Below is the current state of the EChart.

```
<!-- Echart JS CC --> 
<script>

var chart = document.getElementById('cc_chart');
var myChart = echarts.init(chart);

var option = {
    title: { text: '' },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'cross',
            label: {
                backgroundColor: '#6a7985'
            }
        }

    },
    textStyle: {
        color: '#fff'
    },
    grid: {
        left: '0',
        right: '4%',
        bottom: '27%',
        top: '4%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    dataZoom: [
        {
            type: 'inside',
            start: 0,
            end: 100
        },
        {
            show: true,
            type: 'slider',
            y: '75%',
            start: 0,
            end: 100
        }
    ],
    legend: {
        data: ["Bobby", "Freddy"],
        textStyle: {
        },
        textStyle: {
            color: '#fff'
        },
        bottom: 0,
    },
    xAxis: {
        boundaryGap : false,
        data: ["19/03/18","20/03/18","21/03/18","22/03/18","23/03/18","26/03/18","27/03/18","29/03/18","03/04/18"]
    },
    yAxis: {
        boundaryGap : false
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Bobby',
            type: 'line',
            areaStyle: {normal: {}},
            symbol: 'circle',
            symbolSize: 8,
            data: ["011441","011614","011614","003815","001915","003610","000432","000458","005801"]
        },
        {
            name: 'Freddy',
            type: 'line',
            areaStyle: {normal: {}},
            symbol: 'circle',
            symbolSize: 8,
            data: ["001725","001725","001725","003239","010239","002531","005208","004547","002441"]
        },
    ]
};
myChart.setOption(option);
</script>
```

How do I change the int value into a more human readable format, within ECharts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it with the below!

```
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    formatter: function(params) {

        params.sort(function(a,b) { // Sort params by value size first
            return parseInt(b.value) - parseInt(a.value)
        });

        output = '<b>' + params[0].name + '</b><br/>'
        for (i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            output += params[i].marker + params[i].seriesName + ': ' + params[i].value.match(/\d\d/g).join(':'); // : every 2nth

            if (i != params.length - 1) { // Append a <br/> tag if not last in loop
                output += '<br/>'
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

First we sort the params array with a .sort() function, then we create an output containing the date of the first result as the title (*The date will be on every other record, so grabbing it from the first result is fine*), then we iterate over the length of the array, appending values we want to the output (*formatted using [kshetline's answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49634432/9592089)*), and checking if it's the last result in the array so we can add break tags.

Answer (score 2):

If the time value is reliably six characters like in your examples, call the time value t, and formatting would look like this:

```
t.substr(0, 2) + ':' + t.substr(2, 2) + ':' + t.substr(4, 2)
```

Or this, a bit more elegant:

```
t.match(/\d\d/g).join(':')
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I eventually managed to figure it out myself, and have used the code you posted to format the part needed, as shown in my answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

`params.value[0]` contains date in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis',
    formatter: function(params) {
        params = params[0];
        var chartdate = echarts.format.formatTime('dd-MM-yyyy', params.value[0]);
        var val = '<li style="list-style:none">' + params.marker +
            params.seriesName + '&nbsp;&nbsp;' + params.value[1] + '</li>';
        return chartdate + val;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @pujitha-pinky answer you can adapt it to a multiple series chart like this (example with formating the date to a fr-FR local):

```
tooltip = {
    trigger: "axis",
    formatter: function (params) {
     var chartdate = (new Date(params[0].value[0])).toLocaleDateString("fr-FR", {
       year: "numeric",
       month: "2-digit",
       day: "2-digit",
      });
     var vals = params.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + '<li style="list-style:none">' + curr.marker + curr.seriesName + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + curr.value[1] + "</li>", "");
     return chartdate + vals;
    },
   };
```